# jq reshape input for the following strange json

Tags: json, jq, reshape, on-duplicate-key

I'm reading a strange JSON from a customer`s API. I found that JQ command line utility could handle this issue.

What JQ input can group the same field names for the following JSON?

```
{"dados":
{"cor":{"cdCor":"SEM","dsCor":"."}
,"cor":{"cdCor":"RS","dsCor":"ROSE"}
,"cor":{"cdCor":"CB","dsCor":"SAVCHUMBO"}
,"cor":{"cdCor":"KA","dsCor":"KHAKI"}
,"cor":{"cdCor":"SM","dsCor":"MADEIRAS"}
,"grade":{"cdGrade":"3","dsGrade":"SEM TAMANHO"
,"itemGrade":{"cdTamanho":1,"dsTamanho":"."}}
,"grade":{"cdGrade":"4","dsGrade":"PADRAO"
,"itemGrade":{"cdTamanho":1,"dsTamanho":"PP"}
,"itemGrade":{"cdTamanho":5,"dsTamanho":"GG"},
"itemGrade":{"cdTamanho":137,"dsTamanho":"13A14ANOS"}},
"tipoClassificacao":{"cdTipoclas":3,"dsTipoclas":"MODELO"},
"tipoClassificacao":{"cdTipoclas":2,"dsTipoclas":"ARTIGO"},
"tipoClassificacao":{"cdTipoclas":1,"dsTipoclas":"DEPART"},
"tipoClassificacao":{"cdTipoclas":5,"dsTipoclas":"MARCA",
"classificacao":{"cdClassificacao":"960","dsClassificacao":"FMO"},
"classificacao":{"cdClassificacao":"326","dsClassificacao":"DEL RIO"}
}}
```

I would like to output like below:

```
{
  "dados": {
    "cor": [
      {
        "cdCor": "SEM",
        "dsCor": "."
      },
      {
        "cdCor": "RS",
        "dsCor": "ROSE"
      },
      {
        "cdCor": "CB",
        "dsCor": "SAVCHUMBO"
      },
      {
        "cdCor": "KA",
        "dsCor": "KHAKI"
      },
      {
        "cdCor": "SM",
        "dsCor": "MADEIRAS"
      }
    ],
    "grade": [
      {
        "cdGrade": "3",
        "dsGrade": "SEM TAMANHO",
        "itemGrade": [
          {
            "cdTamanho": 1,
            "dsTamanho": "."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "cdGrade": "4",
        "dsGrade": "PADRAO",
        "itemGrade": [
          {
            "cdTamanho": 1,
            "dsTamanho": "PP"
          },
          {
            "cdTamanho": 5,
            "dsTamanho": "GG"
          },
          {
            "cdTamanho": 137,
            "dsTamanho": "13A14ANOS"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tipoClassificacao": [
      {
        "cdTipoclas": 3,
        "dsTipoclas": "MODELO"
      },
      {
        "cdTipoclas": 2,
        "dsTipoclas": "ARTIGO"
      },
      {
        "cdTipoclas": 1,
        "dsTipoclas": "DEPART"
      },
      {
        "cdTipoclas": 5,
        "dsTipoclas": "MARCA"
      }
    ],
    "classificacao": [
      {
        "cdClassificacao": "960",
        "dsClassificacao": "FMO"
      },
      {
        "cdClassificacao": "326",
        "dsClassificacao": "DEL RIO"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: jq's --stream option allows this JSON to be read without loss of information, but what output format are you expecting?

Comment: Hi peak, like explained better above!

Answer (score 1):

[Note: This response was posted before details about the expected output were given.]

Here's one way to use the --stream option to reshape the input so that the output remains a single JSON object.

### Invocation

```
jq -n --stream -f reshape.jq  input.json
```

### reshape.jq

```
def augmentpath($path; $value):
  getpath($path) as $v
  | setpath($path; $v + [$value]);

reduce (inputs | select(length==2)) as $pv
  ({}; augmentpath($pv[0]; $pv[1]) )
```

### Output

```
{
  "dados": {
    "cor": {
      "cdCor": [
        "SEM",
        "RS",
        "VD",
        "RX",
        "ID",
        "UV",
        "OR",
        "AR",
        "BC",
        "CB",
        "KA",
        "SM"
      ],
      "dsCor": [
        ".",
        "ROSE",
        "VERDE",
        "ROXONATAL 81",
        "INDIGO",
        "UVA",
        "ORQUIDEA",
        "AREIA",
        "BCO",
        "SAVCHUMBO",
        "KHAKI",
        "MADEIRAS"
      ]
    },
    "grade": {
      "cdGrade": [
        "3",
        "4"
      ],
      "dsGrade": [
        "SEM TAMANHO",
        "PADRAO"
      ],
      "itemGrade": {
        "cdTamanho": [
          1,
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          137
        ],
        "dsTamanho": [
          ".",
          "PP",
          "P",
          "M",
          "G",
          "GG",
          "13A14ANOS"
        ]
      }
    },
    "tipoClassificacao": {
      "cdTipoclas": [
        3,
        2,
        1,
        5
      ],
      "dsTipoclas": [
        "MODELO",
        "ARTIGO",
        "DEPART",
        "MARCA"
      ],
      "classificacao": {
        "cdClassificacao": [
          "960",
          "326"
        ],
        "dsClassificacao": [
          "FMO",
          "DEL RIO"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi peak, I have just added more information about the output.